# zfs mount points are disappearing on reboot. how to fix it?

Tags: freebsd, zfs

my zfs mountpoints are disappearing on reboot but able to get it back after import. please suggest me the solution?

```
root@mfsbsd:~ # zpool import edjstorage
root@mfsbsd:~ # zfs list
NAME                 USED  AVAIL  REFER  MOUNTPOINT
edjstorage           621M  12.5G    24K  /edjstorage
edjstorage/boot      621M  12.5G   621M  /
edjstorage/conf       24K  12.5G    24K  /conf
edjstorage/storage    24K  12.5G    24K  /storage
```

Comment: `man fstab` # for some insight

Comment: do we need to add mount points in fstab if we use zfs filesystem?.

Comment: if you're using any filesystem, I would presume. I have yet to try zfs. You better google some.

Comment: yes i did already, not required if we use zfs file system. do you have any other ideas to fix this issue

Comment: There most probably is some kind of guide somewhere for "zfs setup and initialization", again google.

Comment: Please post the output of  `zfs get all edjstorage/storage` and `zfs get all edjstorage/conf`. I assume`edjstorage/boot` is mounted after reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Check the `canmount` property of the file systems, like `zfs get canmount edjstorage/boot`. It should be set to `on` and my guess is yours is set to `noauto`. Change it to `on` with `zfs set canmount=on edjstorage/boot`and do this for all file systems you want to automount.

Answer (score 0):

```
# systemctl enable zfs-import-cache
# systemctl enable zfs-mount
# systemctl enable zfs-import.target
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).